# Find the condition on b so that 6th degree polynomial has at least three real roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

Most of the questions on this site ask: Given a polynomial, how to find the number of real roots.

My question is: given a 6th degree polynomial $P_b(x)$: (b lies between 1 and 4)
$$1+b+b^2-bx-2b^2x-2b^3x-b^4x+b^2x^2+3b^3x^2+3b^4x^2+2b^5x^2-b^3x^3-3b^4x^3-5b^5x^3-b^6x^3+b^4x^4+4b^5x^4+3b^6x^4-b^5x^5-3b^6x^5+b^6x^6=0$$

How can I find a condition on $b$ so that $P_b(x)$ has at least three three real roots and $|P_b^{'}(x_i)|<1$ where $x_i$ is a root?

Substituting $y=bx$
$$(1+b+b^2)-(1+2b+2b^2+b^3)y+(1+3b+3b^2+2b^3)y^2-(1+3b+5b^2+b^3)y^3+(1+4b+3b^2)y^4-(1+3b)y^5+y^6=0$$

Comment: first u should collect the lke powers of x :D

Comment: yeah they are written together

Comment: The substitution $y=bx$ will simplify things somewhat.

Comment: sorry it was $3b^3x^2$

Comment: Shobhit means: instead of e.g. $-b^3x^3 -3b^4x^3 -5b^5x^3 - b^6x^3$, you should write $-(b^3+3b^4+5b^5+b^6)x^3$. And I agree.

Comment: Note that the $y=bx$ substitution doesn't work so well with the condition on the derivative.

Comment: Try plotting the polynomial in $y$ for a few values of $b$. You get no real roots for $b=0,1,2,3$ but six for $b=4,5$. Hard to tell for $b=6$ - two might be double roots. Looks like six for $b=8$. None for $b=-1$.

Comment: Where has this come from? Why the complicated functions of $b$ as coefficients?

Comment: This equation has come from $f(f(f(x)))=x$ where $f(x) = bx(1-x)$